# Paginate a search result in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I've set a simple search engine on my CakePHP project which looks like that :

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create("Post", array(
        "action" => "search", 
        "id" => "searchForm"
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input("keyword", array(
        "label" => "",
        "type" => "search",
        "placeholder" => "Recherche..."
    ));
    echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

Here is the controller :

```
function search() {
    $keyword = $this->request->data;
    $keyword = $keyword["Post"]["keyword"];
    $cond = array("OR" => array(
        "Post.title LIKE '%$keyword%'",
        "Post.description LIKE '%$keyword%'"
    ));
    $posts = $this->Post->find("all", array("conditions" => $cond));
    $this->set(compact("posts", "keyword"));
}
```

And it works great. The only problem is when I want to paginate the results. I simply add :

```
$posts = $this->paginate();
```

And here is the problem. When I add this, CakePHP give me all the posts and not only the ones that match the keyword.

So, if you would have a solution, it would be nice :)

Comment: did you take a look at the cake dc search plugin? https://github.com/cakedc/search it does all that in a clean and DRY way - you save yourself a whole lot of trouble re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Yep, that was my very first idea, but, I don't know, it just doesn't want to work. Or I've done something wrong when I set it up...

Comment: most likely the latter - because it works flawlessly for most of us :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the CakePHP book you should be able to do

```
$this->paginate('Post', array(
    'OR' => array(
        'Post.title LIKE' => "%$keyword%",
        'Post.description LIKE' => "%$keyword%"
    )

));
```

Or you can do it like this ( from the cakephp site ).

```
public function list_recipes() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('Recipe.title LIKE' => 'a%'),
        'limit' => 10
    );
    $data = $this->paginate('Recipe');
    $this->set(compact('data'));
);
```

Source:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Comment: Your first solution was what I tried first. But, when I do it like that, I have no results when I do a search :/

Comment: Oh ! Seems to work now. The only problem left and it looks weird to me, is that it seems like it only looks for the keyword in the `Post.description`. If I search for a word which is only in the title and not in the description, it won't find it.

Comment: What kind of SQL is it producing, does it look correct? Does it pick up the OR?

Comment: It seems OK with the `OR`, but it looks like it doesn't convert the `$keyword` variable on the `Post.title : `SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`title`, ... WHERE ((`Post`.`title` LIKE '%$keyword%') OR (`Post`.`description` LIKE '%test%')) ORDER BY `Post`.`created` desc LIMIT 16`

Comment: Man, its not my day. Forgot the double quotes around the title. Edited my answer once again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Paginate does its own lookup on the data I believe. The `find` you are calling previously has no effect on the `paginate`.

Try this:

```
$this->paginate = array( 'conditions' => $cond, ));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Session for storing conditions 
the first, when you submit form you store conditions into Session
and then(paginate) you can read conditions from Session

```
example i want to search the products:
Products/search.ctp
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Product');
    echo $this->Form->input('keyword');
    echo $this->Form->end(__('Search'));
?>
ProductsController.php
<?php 
class ProductsController extends AppController{

public function search() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $keyword = $this->request->data['Product']['keyword'];
            $this->paginate = array(
                'fields' => array('Product.name', 'Product.price', 'Product.created'),
                'order' => array('Product.created' => 'DESC', 'Product.price' => 'DESC'),
                'limit' => 30,
                'conditions' => array('Product.name LIKE' => '%' . $keyword . '%')
            );
            // store array $this->paginate into Session
            $this->Session->write('paginate', $this->paginate);
        }
        $this->paginate = $this->Session->read('paginate');
        $this->set('products', $this->paginate('Product'));
    }
}
```